# Using multiply aggregation with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have several documents that looks like this:

```
{
        "hostname" : "server1.example.com",
        "virtual" : true,
        "processors" : {
                "cores" : 1,
                "sockets" : 4
        }
}
{
        "hostname" : "server2.example.com",
        "virtual" : false,
        "processors" : {
                "cores" : 2,
                "sockets" : 2
        }
}
```

I am trying to output the hostname, virtual and total number of cores for each document.  I keep getting a syntax error that has me stumped.  Here is my query and the syntax error.

```
c.aggregate( {
    $project: {
        hostname: 1,
        total-cores: {$multiply: ["$processors.sockets", "$processors.cores"]},
        virtual: 1,
        _id: 0
    }
});
Thu Apr 25 14:12:18 SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):1
```

Judging from the documentation, this should work.  What am I missing?  I am running MongoDB 2.2.2.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the `total-cores` key so that it's parsed correctly with the embedded hyphen:

```
c.aggregate({ 
    $project: { 
        hostname: 1, 
        "total-cores": {$multiply: ["$processors.sockets","$processors.cores"]}, 
        virtual: 1, 
        _id: 0  
    }
});
```

Comment: It's that simple!  Thank you.  The documentation should be more clear about this.