# Use $multiply on nested fields in aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate in MongoDB.

I have a collection with some items. Each item has an array `rows` and each object in `rows` has fields `quantity` and `price`.

I want to multiply `quantity` and `price`, but I don't know how to specify the fields correctly.

I have tried

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        number: '$number',
      },
      total: {
        $sum: {
          $multiply: [
            '$rows.quantity',
            '$rows.price'
          ]
        }
      },
    }
  }
];
```

but it says that `$multiply` only supports numeric types and not arrays.

So it seems it doesn't understand that `$rows.quantity` is the numeric type field `quantity` in each object in the array.

I guess I should probably use `$each` or something else in order to iterate through the objects in the array.

From [Using multiply aggregation with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221972/using-multiply-aggregation-with-mongodb) I see that I am specifying the fields correctly; however, in that example it is a nested object instead of an array, so maybe I have to use https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/?

## Sample document

```
{
  number: 2,
  rows: [
    {
      quantity: 10,
      price: 312
    },
    {
      quantity: 10,
      price: 312
    },
    {
      quantity: 10,
      price: 312
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can try $unwind which splits arrays and then you can try $multiple.  Here is the link. https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/.  If you can paste the sample document,  I will try and let you know the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method.

Starting in version 3.2 you can use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage to calculates and returns the sum of array of `quantity * price`. Of course to get the array you need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator. The [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator evaluates the value of "quantity" and "price" then returns `0` if they evaluate to a null value. The last stage in the pipeline is the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage where you group your document by "number" and return the "total" for each each group.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "number": 1,  
        "total": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$rows", 
                    "as": "row", 
                    "in": { "$multiply": [ 
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$$row.quantity", 0 ] }, 
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$$row.price", 0 ] } 
                    ]} 
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$number", 
        "total": { "$sum": "$total" } 
    }}
])
```

If you are not on version 3.2 you will need to denormalize the "rows" array before the `$project` stage using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$rows" }, 
    { "$project": { 
        "number": 1,  
        "value": { "$multiply": [
            { "$ifNull": [ "$rows.quantity", 0 ] }, 
            { "$ifNull": [ "$rows.price", 0 ] } 
        ]}
    }}, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$number", 
        "total": { "$sum": "$value" } 
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thank! It seems it makes some errors if either quantity or price is not set. Can I do something to ensure that quantity and price are always evaluated as numbers (i.e. if not set, just treat them as zero)? Or should I just skip rows where either quantity or price are zero, since they wont add to the total anyway?

Comment: @Jamgreen you need to use the `$ifNull` operator to return `0` if "quantity" or price is missing. I've updated the answer. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.